# Is there a way to handle key not found when using operator.itemgetter without using a try-except block?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Is there any other option aside from wrapping `itemgetter` in a `try`/`except` block in case of a missing key?

Like `dict.get('bar', 'foo')`?

Example of usage:

```
currentUser = {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "website": "http://mywebsite.com",
    "description": "I am an actor",
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "phone_number": "+12345678",
    "username": "johndoe",
    "birth_date": "1991-02-23",
    "followers": 46263,
    "following": 345,
    "like": 204,
    "comments": 9
}

id, like, hhh = itemgetter("id","like", "hhh")(currentUser)
```

Comment: Related request on cpython repo: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/58592

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. See the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/operator.py#L288). As mentioned in the comment above, there is an open issue to change the behaviour. Unfortunately, you can't patch attributes like `__init__` directly on a built-in/extension type. Moreover, `operator.itemgetter` is not an acceptable base type, so you can't write a new class to patch it either. The only option would be to write a completely new class from the ground up.

Answer (score 0):

As [adamkgray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8386878/adamkgray) pointed out, I don't think you can do it with `operator.itemgetter`.

But you can use list comprehension to accomplish what you want to do like this.

```py
id, like, hhh = [currentUser.get(f) for f in ['id', 'like', 'hhh']]
```